# Finding invariant set of a non autonomous system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I have been reading about dynamical systems, flows and invariant sets for a while. I have a question that if we are given a system of differential equations, which can be written as

$$\dfrac{d \bar{x}}{dt} = \bar{F} \left( \bar{x}, t \right)$$

can we actually find the flow or the invariant sets without solving the system? In particular, I would like to know the flow/invariant sets of the system of differential equations

\begin{align}
x_1' &= x_2 \\
x_2' &= a \left( t \right) g \left( x_1 \right) + \dfrac{b \left( t \right)}{x_1^{\alpha}} + p \left( t \right)
\end{align}

where the only information available with us is that the functions $a, b, p$ are periodic with period $T$ and are $L^1$. The function $g$ can be anything and $\alpha > 0$. The system is defined for $x_1 > 0$ and $x_2 \in \mathbb{R}$.

I do understand what we mean by invariant sets and flow of this equation. But without the knowledge of the solutions, which cannot be found in the general case, I cannot really proceed with finding the flow and the invariant sets. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Isn't the flow the solution to differential equations for a given initial condition? Maybe invariant sets are something you can tackle for a general problem, but the flow itself seems downright impossible without solving the system explicitly.

Comment: Yes. I thought the same thing. Just wanted to confirm it. Coming to the problem, how can we even find the invariant sets? Because the definition requires flow which cannot be found without solving the system!

Comment: At least invariant sets could be locally constructed at the attractive fixed points of the system

Comment: @DinosaurEgg, in that case, we would need an $x_1$ such that $a \left( t \right) x_1^{\alpha} g \left( x \right) + p \left( t \right) x_1^{\alpha} + b \left( t \right) = 0$ for every $t$. But how to solve it further?

Comment: There is no solving further. First of all this system of ode's is time dependent and since the functions a,p,b are periodic, I'm not sure this thing even has attractors... periodically driven systems usually exhibit centers. Either way, the problem is way too generic to make useful statements about. My bet would be to rely on theorems and estimates based on periodicity and the existence of periodic orbits.